# How to dismiss popup notification? For automation testing using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

My task is to login facebook and to go on main page. After my code enters facebook it shows this notification and my code crashes. How can I disable this so that code continues working?

I'm new in Python
Thanks in advance.

Image of the error: 
[Popup error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlXEP.png)

Comment: Can you give us your code or the error message it displays when it crashes?

Comment: You need to post your code here, for us to be able to help

Answer (score 4):

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
```

or in python, that would be

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```